# Symfony 2 multiple routes possibilities for a bundle

Tags: symfony, routes, hostname

I would like to access the routes for a bundle with 2 different methods :

- secondsite.domain/
- domain/secondsite/

I don't want to use domain/ as it is already used for another site/bundle.

Both methods separatly work fine, but if I put both in the routing.yml, the last one overrides the other.

The method for sudbomain.domain/ :

```
annexes_domain:
    resource: "@SecondSiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    host:     "secondsite.domain"
    prefix:   /
```

The method for domain/secondsite/ :

```
annexes_default:
    resource: "@SecondSiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /secondsite/
```

Does anyone know how to make both methods work at the same time ?

Comment: `first_route:
    pattern:   /first/choose/date
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:chooseDate }

second_route:
    pattern:   /second/choose/date
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:chooseDate }` both are pointing to the same action, this works having multiple route for 1 action but yours is slightly different as you add the controller as resource.

Comment: Try add 'host: "domain"' to the second entry